# Xamarin WCF Fails in Release Mode

Tags: android, .net, wcf, xamarin.android, xamarin

Platform: Xamarin Studio 4

Target Mobile: Android

I have an android app that calls a WCF service using basicHttpBinding that I have been working on using Xamarin Studio 4 that is running perfectly fine while in Debug Mode.  To simplify things while troubleshooting this, I am calling a "Hello World" function of the WCF.  No input parameters and only a string output.

In debug mode, I get the "Hello World" response.  When I switch the application build to "Release", and run the application again, I get the following error message:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNoFoundException: A system exception has occured. ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (No route to host) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketExcpetion: No route to host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in filename unknown: 0

The code that is calling the WCF is:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp ();
BTSMobileWcfClient _client = new BTSMobileWcfClient (binding, endPoint);
_client.SayHelloCompleted += ClientOnSayHelloCompleted;
_client.SayHelloAsync();

private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
            };
            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            return binding;
        }

private void ClientOnSayHelloCompleted(object sender, SayHelloCompletedEventArgs sayHelloCompletedEventArgs)
        {
            string msg = null;

            if (sayHelloCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
            {
                msg = sayHelloCompletedEventArgs.Error.ToString();
            }
            else if (sayHelloCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled)
            {
                msg = "Request was cancelled.";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = sayHelloCompletedEventArgs.Result.ToString();
            }
            RunOnUiThread(() =>{
                var lblSignInError = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lblSignInError);
                lblSignInError.Text = msg;
            });
        }
```

The BTSMobileWcfClient is a .cs file created by using the tool SLsvcUtil.exe against the .svc file for the web service.  I am not sure if this has anything to do with it or not but wanted to document this in case.

Does anyone have any suggestion or seen this before where it runs fine in "debug mode" but fails in "release mode"?

Thank you!

Comment: The endPoint is a variable in the class that is private static readonly EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("xxxxx"); where xxxxx is pointing to our http://xxx.xxx.xxx/*.svc file.

Comment: Sometimes the WCF deserialization in release mode can also fail because of Xamarin's linking feature. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15531/wcf-fails-in-release-mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I`ve just run into the same problem in release compilation of my project. After awhile of wandering around I set internet permission on in ProjectOptions->AndroidApplication->Required permissions (in Xamarin studio). It looks working for me

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio, Add the next lines in android.manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution #1:

---

- Set internet permission
- PorjectOptions->Android Application->Internet

## Solution #2:

---

1. Create a new file called System.ServiceModel.xml in the root.
2. Change build action of System.ServiceModel.xml to LinkDescription.
3. Add the following to the System.ServiceModel.xml.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <linker>
      <assembly fullname="System.ServiceModel">
           <type fullname="System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1">
               <method name="CreateChannel" />
            </type>
       </assembly>
   </linker>
   ```
4. Ensure Linker Settings are set to SDK Assemblies only.